# Ionic 2 Modal does not dismiss

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to dismiss my modal in ionic 2.

I have component which looks like this:

```
export class DynamicModalComponent<T extends IHasId> {

    modalOptions: DynamicModalOptions<T>

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.modalOptions = navParams.get('modalOptions');
    }

    close() {
        this.modalOptions.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar align-title="center">
    <ion-title> Dynamic Modal Header </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="close()" ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="save"></ion-icon>
        &nbsp;Cancel
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

When I click the cancel button, my function gets triggered but nothing dismisses.   I don't think the issue would be in the calling class but just incase ill post the relevant pieces:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navParams: NavParams, public baseProvider: UserSkills,
    public enumProvider: Enums, public modalCtrl: ModalController, routes: Routes) {
}

showModal(modalOptions: DynamicModalOptions<UserSkill>) {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(DynamicModalComponent, { modalOptions });
    modal.present();
    return modal;
}

onItemClick(entity) {
    var modalOptions = this.getDynamicModalOptions(entity);
    this.showModal(modalOptions);
}

getDynamicModalOptions(entity: UserSkill): DynamicModalOptions<UserSkill> {
    var modalOptions = new DynamicModalOptions<UserSkill>();

    modalOptions.entity = entity;
    modalOptions.editOptions = this.editOptions;
    modalOptions.inputMetadata = this.getInputMetadata(); 
    modalOptions.viewCtrl = this.viewCtrl;

    return modalOptions;
}
```

Comment: Does `getDynamicModalOptions` get called this way? I'm not sure of the need to couple `ViewController` since you can always inject it in the constructor for `DynamicModalComponent`

Comment: Really, I gotta investigate because ViewController and NavController are special they can't be inject into providers easily,  this code was originally done thorough a provider but I extracted it into a component

Comment: @OluwafemiSule that fixed it, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it correct!

Comment: Yes, the problem was that you were passing the wrong instance of the `ViewController`. You were passing the instance of the `ViewController` of the caller, and not the `ViewController` that represents the modal. Therefore the `viewCtrl.dismiss();`didn't do anything (since the modal exists in the `DynamicModalComponent ` and not the caller component). Another way to fix this kind of issues, is to use the injector (`public injector: Injector`) to get the right instance (`viewCtrl = this.injector.get(ViewController);`) on the `DynamicModalComponent` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @sebaferras, the wrong instance of ViewController is being passed here.

You can ask the injector to get the right instance of ViewController by injecting the `Injector` in the constructor of `DynamicModalComponent`. This way `ViewController` can be resolved in `ngOnInit`.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
            public navParams: NavParams, 
            private injector: Injector) {
  this.modalOptions = navParams.get('modalOptions');
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.viewCtrl = this.injector.get(ViewController);
}

close() {
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

A **better** technique is to inject `ViewController` in the constructor of `DynamicModalComponent` and have Angular take care of things for you.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
            public navParams: NavParams, 
            private viewCtrl ViewController) {
  this.modalOptions = navParams.get('modalOptions');
}

close() {
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```